# I have pictures of 2 graphs and I need to extract the curves, change colors and paste both on a same graph in order to compare them

Tags: charts, colors, gimp, extract

so basically the title.
[Here's the graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPiEN.png), so basically I need to compare both charts. I'd like to take the curve on one chart, change its color and paste it over the second one like on this chart [teacher did this one and i basically want to do the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cbFE.png).
Hope that it's not a repost and thx in advance for your answers !

Comment: You could use photoshop (or similar) to overlay the images on top of each other...

But it's very likely that the 'teacher' didn't do that... they generated a graph from scratch with both sets of data.

Do you have the data to generate the graph?

Comment: Unfortunately no, the technology he used is somewhat tricky so he made the charts for us to analyse...

Answer (score 1):

- Cut the image into two graphs:

  - Duplicate the layer
  - Make a rectangle selection that covers one of the graphs
  - `Layer>Crop to selection`
  - Select the other layer
  - `Select>Invert`
  - `Layer>Crop to selection`, you should now have two non-overlapping layers.
- Select the layer that you want to move
- Make it transparent: `Layer>Transparency>Add alpha channel` (if grayed out, the alpha channel is alredy there)
- Recolor the graph:

  - Make a rectangle selection that covers the graph (and excludes the scales)
  - `Color>Color to alpha` and remove the white (default). The background of the chart will turn to transparency (indicated by a checkerboard pattern)
  - [Set the alpha-lock](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-dialogs-structure.html#idp8762800) on the layer
  - Bucket-fill the selection with the new color
- Move the graph over the other one. Remember that by default the Move tool only grabs opaque parts, so click on the graph (or depress the shift key)
- If necessary crop the image (`Image>Fit canvas to layers`)

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your answer, I was able to do most part but I still have small issues:

- I can't seem to keep a good picture quality, I don't know if it comes from the original pictures but when I try to save/copy it (picture with 2 charts), the scales and curves are all blurry and the background is already transparent.

- I can't seem to bucket-fill with a color, only with a pattern...

Beside that, thanks a lot for taking your time to write that, it's really useful to me!

Comment: Sorry I think I figured out how to format a comment lol

Last issue too, the picture I exported doesn't have any background, any way I can add one ?

Edit : I don't know how to format

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the original files. If these are GIFs, convert to RGB before working on them (`Image>Mode>RGB`) and export the result to PNG. To add a background, add a layer (initialized to white) and drag in down in the Layer stack (or `Layer>Stack>Layer to bottom`).

Comment: Here's a link to the original file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IrqoRFsKlyXXXg2Uo10e5sqi9DA2KKBQ , opening it with powerpoint seems better than G slides. If it takes too much time from you, don't bother with it I'll do like you said earlier but thank you nonetheless!

Comment: Unfortunately I can only confirm that the pictures in the PPT are of poor quality, they are obviously scaled down versions of larger pictures (the PPTX format is a ZIP, you can extract the pictures easily).

Comment: Doing like you said I was able to extract the pictures, thank you I'll try to work with that from now on.